# how to change the datetime format in admin panel?

Tags: python, django

I have an answer model with str method as defined below:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return  "(" + str(self.created_at)  + ")"
```

I would like to show in this format Feb. 27, 2021, 6:55 p.m in the admin panel

but it shows like this in admin panel

[image]

How can i achieve the above format? Thanks for the help!

**SOLUTION:**

So it turns out this can be done without any external libraries like pytz.

here is the solution i went with.

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

In the str method of the model

```
def __str__(self):
    return  "(" + timezone.localtime(self.created_at).strftime('%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p')  + ")"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTimeField holds a datetime.datetime object.

You can convert that object by using the object's `strftime` method. An official reference is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

In your case, try

```
created_at_str = created_at.strftime('%b %d, %y, %I:%M %p')
```

Comment: sorry the time is incorrect. i have set timezone to kathmandu. looks like it uses someother timezone. is there a way to take the timezone into account when doing the date formatting? thanks!

Comment: @kofhearts Datetime objects are timezone-naïve. Have a look at https://pypi.org/project/pytz/ to help you convert your time to the correct timezone.

Comment: thanks moosearch. i went with the above solution i posted above.